# What is the production volume for film over the last decade?

Tags: film, business, fujifilm, kodak

How many rolls/sheets of film has Kodak/Fuji/the-whole-industry produced each year for the last ten years?

What has the revenue been?

I've tried googling for the answer but a summary of this information appears elusive.

I'd like to get an impression of whether or not the decline of film has stopped and if it has now stabilized as a niche market.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a graph of Kodak film sales on [this page](http://photo.net/film-and-processing-forum/00XQGG).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another source of data

[image: US film sales - in millions of dollars]